# Alternate code to supress "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Below is my current code:**

```
row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
df[row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","")] = row_data['FINDING'].strip()
df[row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","") + ' Further Comments'] = row_data['FURTHER COMMENTS'].strip()
```

**Warning:**

C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10588\1664916535.py:38: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
df[row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","")] = row_data['FINDING'].strip()

**Replacement:**

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([row_data['FINDING'].strip()],
        columns = [row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","")])],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
                        
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([row_data['FURTHER COMMENTS'].strip()],
        columns = [row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","") + ' Further Comments'])],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```

The replacement code however does not work as expected. I compared the output and they differ. I fail to understand why. Need some Python expert to advice please.

### Sample value of row_data(each row is a result of one iteration of for-loop) :

```
{'EXAMINATION': 'PSA', 'FINDING': '1.80ug/L', 'FURTHER COMMENTS': 'Normal range 0.00-2.99ug/L'}
{'EXAMINATION': 'FIT Test', 'FINDING': 'YYY', 'FURTHER COMMENTS': 'XXX'}
{'EXAMINATION': 'Height:', 'FINDING': '1.78m', 'FURTHER COMMENTS': 'BB'}
{'EXAMINATION': 'Weight:', 'FINDING': '82kg', 'FURTHER COMMENTS': 'AA'}
```

What I am trying is to flatten this in the dataframe:

[image]

**Full Code that I am using :**

```
    document = Document(f)
    table = document.tables[2]

    keys = None
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    # Establish the mapping based on the first row
    # headers; these will become the keys of our dictionary
        if i == 0:
            keys = tuple(text)
            continue

        row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
        df[row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","")] = row_data['FINDING'].strip()
        df[row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","") + ' Further Comments'] = row_data['FURTHER COMMENTS'].strip()
        #df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([row_data['FINDING'].strip()],
         #                               columns = [row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","")])],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
                        
        #df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([row_data['FURTHER COMMENTS'].strip()],
         #                               columns = [row_data['EXAMINATION'].replace(":","") + ' Further Comments'])],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data to work with

Comment: @HimanshuPanwar Edited the question. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you provided:

```py
row_data = [
    {
        "EXAMINATION": "PSA",
        "FINDING": "1.80ug/L",
        "FURTHER COMMENTS": "Normal range 0.00-2.99ug/L",
    },
    {"EXAMINATION": "FIT Test", "FINDING": "YYY", "FURTHER COMMENTS": "XXX"},
    {"EXAMINATION": "Height:", "FINDING": "1.78m", "FURTHER COMMENTS": "BB"},
    {"EXAMINATION": "Weight:", "FINDING": "82kg", "FURTHER COMMENTS": "AA"},
]
```

Here is an easier and faster way to do it by preprocessing outside of Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

flattened_data = {}
for item in row_data:
    flattened_data[item["EXAMINATION"]] = [item["FINDING"]]
    flattened_data[f"{item['EXAMINATION']} FURTHER COMMENTS"] = [
        item["FURTHER COMMENTS"]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_data)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

        PSA        PSA FURTHER COMMENTS FIT Test FIT Test FURTHER COMMENTS   
0  1.80ug/L  Normal range 0.00-2.99ug/L      YYY                       XXX  \

  Height: Height: FURTHER COMMENTS Weight: Weight: FURTHER COMMENTS  
0   1.78m                       BB    82kg                       AA
```

Comment: Why should I loop in the Dictionary when I can do that without it. Do you have any other alternate of achieving this without loop.  Also, each line in my sample data is a result of one iteration and is not just a fully formed Dictionary at once(like the raw_data you have taken)

Comment: hi Laurent, Added the full code in the actual post. Please check if it helps.

Comment: Hi, most importantly, could you provide a proper of `row_data`? What is it? A list of dictionaries? A list of lists of dictionaries? Cheers.

Comment: hi Larent, the "Sample value of row_data" that you see, is a result of for-loop iterating 4 times - every row is an output of each iteration. So, row_data is just a dictionary at the end.